# Can't get child element from parent component

Tags: angular

Im trying to get a child element from parent component with `@ViewChild`, but I got a problem, because my child component must be launched from parent function. And after such thing I cant get a child. It works fine, when child component starts with `ngOnInit` or whatever, but doesn't work with my function... What am I doing wrong and how to get it work?

My parent comp:

```
export class MainScreenComponent {

    @ViewChild('myChild') child;
    showMyChild = false;

    getMyChild() {
        this.showMyChild = true;
        console.log(this.child.mytest); //undefined
    }

}
```

My parent temp:

```
<button (click)="getMyChild()">Start My Child Comp</button>
<hr>
<div *ngIf="showMyChild==true">
    <div my-child #myChild></div>
</div>
```

My child comp:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[my-child]'
})

export class StdOrderComponent {
    mytest = 'This goes to parent';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your varibale to child component is not initialized because `<div my-child #myChild></div>` is not in the DOM when `showMyChild = false`.

I know 2 solutions:

1. Use `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`, so element is always there, but hidden

```html
<div [hidden]="showMyChild">
    <div my-child #myChild></div>
</div>
```

2. Handle `AfterView` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#afterview (I could be wrong about exact life-cycle hook) in order to catch the moment when child component is added to the DOM.

P.S. You don't need to compare a `boolean` variable with `true`:

`*ngIf="showMyChild==true"` is the same as *ngIf="showMyChild"

Comment: Andrei, thank you for quick reply! `[hidden]` can't be applied here, cause `my-child` launches a `POST` request on init with big and bold data. So `ngAfterViewChecked` was right idea. Thank you. But after that I understood, that I actually need an `@output` for my purposes %)